# Using a html select box with razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a html selector, and I want to use the selected value for my "model => model.type" in my form. Is there a way to set the value in my `@Html.EditorFor(model => model.type)` to the value of the selector?

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)
<fieldset>
    <legend>Bet</legend>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.type)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">

        <select id ="type">
  <option value="Football">Football</option>
  <option value="Rugby">Rugby</option>
  <option value="Horse Racing">Horse Racing</option>
</select>

        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.type)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.type)

    </div>



    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Create" />
    </p>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: can not you do this with Razor, you have to use Javascript, can you use jQuery?

Comment: Why do you need two controls for the type property? Do you have any specific reasons not to use just a drop down list?

Comment: sorry, my mistake, I understood you wanted to put the value of "select" in the "input"

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can try with this options:

Model:

```
public string Type { get; set; }

public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> TypeList
{
    get
    {
        return new List<SelectListItem>
        {
            new SelectListItem { Text = "Football", Value = "Football"},
            new SelectListItem { Text = "Rugby", Value = "Rugby"},
            new SelectListItem { Text = "Horse Racing", Value = "Horse Racing"}
        };
    }
}
```

HTML (Razor):

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Type, Model.TypeList)
```

OR

HTML (Razor):

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Type, new SelectList(new string[] {"Football", "Rugby", "Horse Racing"}, Model.Type))
```

Comment: I am getting: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: I just want to highlight that there are two classes with the name `SelectListItem`, the one you want is in `System.Web.Mvc` and **not** the one in `System.Web.WebPages.Html`.

Comment: Hi @NickG, are you continue with the problem? maybe you can create a question and then you can copy here the link

Comment: I have the same exception as @Nick

Comment: @andresdescalzo this solution does not work. It throws object reference not set to an instance of an object. Any idea on why it is throwing that exception?

Answer (score 5):

@andresdescalzo's solution (last one) works with a minor change:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Type, new SelectList(new string[] {"Football", "Rugby", "Horse Racing"}, "Rugby"), htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
```

**First:** Add a selected item for dropdown list (e.g. "Rugby")

**Second:** remove last `Model.Type` and add `htmlAttributes`

*PS: SelectedList open parentheses closed after selected item of list (here is "`Rugby`")*

Answer (score 1):

The solution provided by @andresdescalzo works only when we pass the model from Controller to the view.

```
public class SomeController : Controller
{
  public ActionResult SomeAction()
  {
    return View(new SomeModelWithIEnumerationsSelectListItem())
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An addition to the existing answers: If you get the exception "object reference not set to an instance of an object" when implementing @andresdescalzo's solution, you either need to:

1. Return the model that you are working with as @diwas mentioned
2. Instantiate a model on the razor page so you can call the method. This is helpful if you are using a ViewModel instead of a simple EF model.

The second can be done like this:

```
@{ var tempModel = new YourNameSpace.Models.YourModel(); }
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Type, tempModel.TypeList, Model.Type))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the Razor View

```
    <div class="editor-field col-md-3">          
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Servers, 
          Model.AvailableServers,new { @class = "form-control" })  
         @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SqlServerName)
    </div>
```

Dynamic DropDown from controller

```
        List<SelectListItem> ServersAvailable = new List<SelectListItem>();
            bool IdSelected = false;
            ServersAvailable.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "......Select your server name......", Value = "" });
            for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                ServersAvailable.Add(new SelectListItem
                {

                    Text = dt.Rows[i].ItemArray[0].ToString(),
                    Value = dt.Rows[i].ItemArray[0].ToString(),
                    Selected = IdSelected
                });
            }
```